# Drawing in a view on the fly

Tags: android

In my activity I am planning to draw a rectangle or a arrow whenever user encircles a region.
I sure that there exist ways to draw on a view, but all I can find is override the onDraw function. Which is in my case not feasible, as I am planning to draw a pixel from my onclick handler.

I Hope there should be some code in the following manner but I havent found it yet..

```
View v; 
s = v.GetFrawingSurface()
s.PutPixel(x,y,rgb);
```

Please help in this...

Answer (score 0):

Put a blank View above the View you're about to draw in ViewGroup.
Then in onDraw of that View you can draw whatever you want and it will appear on top of the content.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    //... your content here

    <com.your.packagename.widget.YourCustomView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now tell your View to draw what you need

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        yourView.drawPixel(event.getX(), event.getY());
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

And your view

```
public final class YourView extends View {


    public void drawPixel(float x, float y) {
        //store filled pixels somewhere... (matrix is not a Matrix clas here, just an example)
        matrix.addValues(x, y);
        invalidate(); //cal this to call onDraw();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        // get pixels from matrix and draw them

        for(...) {

            c.drawPoint(currentX, currentY, paint);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I could do that but then I have to route all events from overlay to activity. Is there any simple way. IMHO there has to be a method to just draw,